# Ember Object, with a nested array

Tags: ember.js

To learn Ember, I've been trying to make a simple app that computes timezones.

When a person enters their city, and the other person's city, I make a GET request to my API, which returns the dates like so --

```
great_times: [array]
good_for_me: [array]
good_for_them: [array]
```

In handlebars, I have

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <header>
      <h2>We found <span class="twenty-four-header">{{totalTimes}}</span>
        great meeting {{pluralize totalTimes 'time' 'times'}} for you!</h2>
    </header>

    <div class="main-content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            {{view RightTime.AutoCompleteAddressView value=myCity placeholder="What's your city?" 
              class="form-control input-lg" latLng=myLatLng}}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            {{view RightTime.AutoCompleteAddressView value=theirCity placeholder="What their city?"
              class="form-control input-lg" latLng=theirLatLng}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {{#each meetingTime in greatTimes}}
        {{render 'meetingTime' meetingTime }}
      {{/each}}
    </div><!--main-content-->
  </div>
</div>
```

This works, but what happens is that when I update the city, It no longer updates this each loop.

I do know however that the model was updated, because the {{totalTimes}} computed property does update.

This is what my meeting Object looks like:

```
RightTime.Meeting = Ember.Object.extend({
  meetingTimes: null,
  myCity: null,
  theirCity: null,
  myLatLng: null,
  theirLatLng: null,

  totalTimes: function() {
    if (this.meetingTimes) {
      return this.meetingTimes.great_times.length;
    }
  }.property('meetingTimes'),

  locationsData: function() {
    return {
      myLatLng: [this.myLatLng.k, this.myLatLng.A],
      theirLatLng: [this.theirLatLng.k, this.theirLatLng.A]
    }
  }.property('myLatLng', 'theirLatLng'),

  findTimes: function() {
    var meeting = this;
    if (this.myLatLng && this.theirLatLng) {
      $.ajax({ 
        url: 'api/meetings',
        type: 'GET',
        data: meeting.get('locationsData')
      }).done(function(response){
        meeting.set('meetingTimes', Ember.A(response));
      });
    }
  }.property('myLatLng', 'theirLatLng')
});
```

I have a feeling that the problem lies in

```
.done(function(response){
            meeting.set('meetingTimes', Ember.A(response));
          });
```

I'm resetting the whole meetingtimes array, which may be the wrong way to go about it.

How would you go about making the meetingTimes arrray update and reflect in handlebars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably just move `great_times` into a computed property that depends on `meetingTimes` and isn't chained.

something like

```
greatTimes: function() {
  return Em.get(this, 'meetingTimes.great_times') || [];
}.property('meetingTimes'),
```

With a template like this

```
{{#each meetingTime in greatTimes}}
  {{render 'meetingTime' meetingTime }}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Hey Kingpin, I added this update, but it still doesn't seem to be working in some cases. When I try Toronto and New York, I get 12. Then, when I change it Toronto to Osaka, I should only get 1, but instead the 1 gets appended to the each loop. you can take a look here-> http://infinite-caverns-7086.herokuapp.com

Comment: Would you mind sharing your templates?  If I were to guess I'd say there is a problem with your template (like non-matching tags, or invalid html).

Comment: Hi kingpin, sure, will update the snippet here. The full github for the app is here -- https://github.com/stopachka/right-time

Comment: Oh my god, you were right! It was a closing div tag the meetingTime.handlebars template. Mr. Kingpin, big gratitude!

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear you found it.